# Declare cypress config with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress, eslint, typescript-typings

I'm trying to move a setup-helper file to ts definition, but I'm having the next error:

```js
Property 'domainName' does not exist on type 'Config'
```

and it comes from this statement:

```js
const { domainName } = Cypress.config();
```

My cypress.json file contains that `domainName` config:

```js
//cypress.json

{
  domainName: 'name',
  //...
}
```

And the tests are working with it.

I've tried adding this [ts-config](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfigjson) without success.
How can I add the cypress config definition?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most optimal way, but it satisfies the Typescript linter.

Since you're using `cypress.json`, you would just need an extended type that includes your particular key `domainName`.

You can apply the `extends` keyword to `Cypress.Config` to define the extension. Define it as an `interface` because `type` does not allow the `extends` keyword.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

interface ExtendedConfig extends Cypress.Config {
  domainName?: string
}

it('uses extended config in Cypress-Typescript', () => {
  const config: ExtendedConfig = Cypress.config()
  const { domainName } = config
  cy.log(domainName)
})
```

---

**Later Cypress versions**

If you upgrade Cypress to a version > 10, you would be using `cypress.config.ts` and the above may not work in that case.

The "usual" practice is to add your own variables to env rather than config, and access them as follows, which should be type-safe:

```js
const { domainName } = Cypress.env();
```